# How to skip run time error in tibco?

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I am new to tibco and I am working on tibco BW 5.X versions.

I have a scenario where I am working on multiple records coming in from a schema and I have to write a text file with only specific values out of those records.

Ex :

if this is the input:

```
<param>1</param>
<param>2</param>
<param>1</param>
<param>1</param>
```

I only have to write the param having values 1 and have to generate error for param having values 2 but after generating error the iteration that is currently going on should continue and must not stop.

I would be grateful if someone can help

Answer (score 2):

I assume in case of the value "2" you want to invoke the "Generate Error" Activity to throw an error up to a calling process or client that some entry was not correct, right?

So if you want to make sure to process the whole list you should not throw the error in the loop group on the list as it will exit.
You can either:

1. Use 2 seperated lists

   map the entries with value "1" into a good list that enter the loop and entries with value "2" into a bad list, that will if filled let you then invoke the "Generate Error" activity after the loop processing.
2. Append the entries with value "2" in your loop
   Thereby after processing the loop you have these entries and if the list contains entries invoke the "Generate Error" activity.

Hope that helps
            Cheers Seb

P.s.: if you upload your process it would be more clear to show ;)

Comment: Thanks Seb for your superb suggestion , I applied the logic suggested by you and it is working fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a output schema which contains only param1 values and use a *mapper activity* to perform corresponding transformation and *xpath* functions for filtering. If you try to implement this solution you can eliminate the chance of param2 values creeping into your output.

Comment: Thanks Tarun for your suggestion . :)